# Deletar linhas vazias no final de um arquivo CSV com PHP

Tags: php, csv

Olá, preciso de uma dica, fui fazer uma importação de um arquivo em `CSV` para alterar um registro em minha base de dados e estranhamente não consegui faze lo, fiz uma análise no código em `PHP` e está tudo certo então parti para o arquivo em `CSV` e descobri que o mesmo após os teste que fiz ficou com linhas em branco ao final do mesmo, fiz uma limpeza e novamente refiz o processo de importação e tudo deu certo.
Existe alguma possibilidade de eliminar essas linhas após os registros no momento da importação?

O que tenho é isso:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
        $Dados = file($tempFile);
        // IGNORANDO A PRIMEIRA LINHA DO CSV
        array_shift($Dados);

        foreach($Dados as $RegLinhas) {

            // RETIRA ESPAÇOS NO INÍCIO E FIM
            $Linha = trim($RegLinhas);
            // DIVIDE A STRING
            $CamposImport = explode(';', $Linha);
            // RECUPERANDO EM VARIÁVES PARA ORGANIZAR SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE
            $IdPessoa = $CamposImport[0];       
            $Nome = $CamposImport[1];
            $IdUnicoop = $CamposImport[2];
            $DataAdmissao = $CamposImport[3];
            $IdCargo = $CamposImport[4];
            $LotacaoRH = $CamposImport[5];
            $CTPS = $CamposImport[6];
            $CTPSSerie = $CamposImport[7];
            $CTPSUF = $CamposImport[8];
            $DataNascimento = $CamposImport[9];
            $CPF = $CamposImport[11];           
            // CONVERTENDO DATA PARA MYSQL
            $DataAdmissao = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$DataAdmissao)));     
            $DataNascimento = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$DataNascimento))); 

            // CAMPOS  FIXOS
            $TipoColaborador = "Funcionario";
            $DivulgarAniversario = 1;
            $Categoria = "F";
            $ClienteProdutor = "C";
            $Fornecedor = 0;
            $Colaborador = 1;
            $Ativo = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode fazer um If nos campos que nunca aparecerao vazios. Por exemplo: If IdPessoa diferente de vazio, recebe as outras informações...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @BrunoFolle, vou fazer uns testes.